# Datepicker - 2 rules for date input by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have an input field which accepts input from user:

```
  <div class="four columns">
     <label>Date of birth (DD/MM/YYYY)<span class="text-red">*</span </label>
     <input id="dob2" class="datepicker" name="dob2" class="input" type="text"><span class="dateico"><img src="img/steps_breadcrumb/ico_calendar.png"></span>
  </div>
```

This input is currently only allowing user above 16. This is the JS code for the datepicker:

```
      $(document).ready (function () {
        $('#dob2').datepicker();
        $('#dob2').datepicker ("option", "changeMonth", true);
        $('#dob2').datepicker ("option", "changeYear", true);
        $('#dob2').datepicker ("option", "yearRange", "-100:-16");
        $('#dob2').datepicker ("option", "maxDate", "-16Y");
        $('#dob2').datepicker ("option", "minDate", "-100Y");
      });
```

But what I want it to do is - if the user inputed either 16 / 17 there will be a prompter with a special message or an alert message below the input box saying something.

Comment: what datepiker is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your datepicker limits the Year to 2000, I'm assuming the 16/17 means the day of the month.. 
You can use the onSelect event handler inbuilt with datepicker.
So your function becomes 
`$('#dob2').datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: "-100:-16",
          maxDate: "-16Y",
          minDate: "-100Y",
          onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                var day  = date.getDate();

                if(day==16 || day== 17){
                    alert("show your message");
                }
           }
        });`

You can find the fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pjoriginal/qkbhf9rq/1/)

Comment: 16 / 17 mean if they user inputed an age of 16 or 17 so their year would 2000 or 1999

Comment: @rory-h use the date.getFullYear() instead of date.getDate().. then check accordingly